# Force Wordpress to create Thumbnails of same Size as the uploaded Image

Tags: image, wordpress, resize

AFAIK, Wordpress only generates Thumbnails (e.g., 'large') only when the desired image size is *smaller* (and not when the target size would be the same).

I use

> `add_image_size( 'referenzen-big', 627, 490, true );`

So if my customer uploads a file with 627x490px, the original Image will be used.

But this is not desired, since this customed, in all good faith, uploads the images in the right size, and also highest possible .jpg-compression. This results in images being around 300kB in this case.

A pratical, but technicall not flawless way would be to ask him to upload his images in 628x490, so 1px more width, forcing a rescale. Suggestions like this will not be accepted :-)

So far, I've investigated the hooks responsible for image creation, and tracked the responsible function down; here's the last hook I found:
[image_make_intermediate_size()](http://xref.yoast.com/2.9/nav.html?wp-includes/media.php.source.html#l416)

this is the function responsible for the actual resizing:
[image_resize_dimensions()](http://xref.yoast.com/2.9/wp-includes/media.php.source.html#l266).
There's even a line saying:

```
// if the resulting image would be the same size or larger we don't want to resize it
if ( $new_w >= $orig_w && $new_h >= $orig_h )
    return false;
```

So how can I enable this "force resize" feature?

Comment: as far as I might understand your concern, may I ask what is the problem of using the original size when available ?

Comment: The uploaded images are too big, around 300kB, way too much for the page in question.

Comment: you can always reduce the quality (if it is jpg) : `add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_quality_callback');
function jpeg_quality_callback($arg) {
return (int)100; // or 80 or whatever
} `

Comment: please note this paragraph:
> But this is not desired, since this customed, in all good faith, uploads the images in the right size, and also highest possible .jpg-compression. This results in images being around 300kB in this case.

Comment: Check the accepted answer in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/image-dimensions-same-as-image-size for a good answer to this question. You can achieve the same with wp_get_attachment_image()

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution you are looking for, to be placed in your functions.php file:

```
function thumbnail_upscale( $default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h, $crop ){
    if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'thumbnail_upscale', 10, 6 );
```

This is found here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50649/how-to-scale-up-featured-post-thumbnail

It will upscale images and generate thumbnails for all image sizes.  The only downfall, which probably isn't a downfall, is that no matter what you'll get a separate file for each image size for all uploaded images... even if it's a small icon or something.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While still not optimal, wouldn't it be better to use a serverside library like [Timthumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) and then provide the original source and use the 'q' (= quality) parameter?

That would optimize the image, with the original size.

Might be some caveats, but really - anything is better than modifying the core.

Answer (score 0):

If disk space is not the issue but just download speed as in my case...

The issue I was facing was the the client was not paying attention to size or dimension for the feature image uploads. The theme is a responsive theme and works well with the range of image heights and scaling to the desired image width in the page. So it was possible to upload very large files and not notice the size if sitting on a high speed network.

I added custom image sizes, used a plugin to force regeneration and modified the theme to display the custom size instead.

Comment: What plugin did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem: a client website should generate bigger thumbs. I've ended up building a plugin with a custom Image Editor, like this:

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-image-editor.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php';

function im_add_image_editor($implementations) {
    array_unshift($implementations, 'IM_Image_Editor_GD');
    return $implementations;
}
add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'im_add_image_editor');
```

The IM_Image_Editor_GD extends WP_Image_Editor_GD, changes the _resize function (who calls `image_resize_dimensions`) to call an internal version of it, like this:

```
class IM_Image_Editor_GD extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function __destruct() {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

    protected function _resize( $max_w, $max_h, $crop = false ) {
        $dims = $this->image_resize_dimensions( $this->size['width'], $this->size['height'], $max_w, $max_h, $crop );
        if ( ! $dims ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'error_getting_dimensions', __('Could not calculate resized image dimensions'), $this->file );
        }
        list( $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h ) = $dims;

        $resized = wp_imagecreatetruecolor( $dst_w, $dst_h );
        imagecopyresampled( $resized, $this->image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h );

        if ( is_resource( $resized ) ) {
            $this->update_size( $dst_w, $dst_h );
            return $resized;
        }

        return new WP_Error( 'image_resize_error', __('Image resize failed.'), $this->file );
    }

    protected function image_resize_dimensions($orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop = false) {
        // Copied original image_resize_dimensions and changed the test
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and sorry about my English!

Answer (score -1):

You can manage with this plugin visit https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/

#### Simple Image Sizes

This plugin allow create custom image sizes for your site. Override your theme sizes directly on the media option page. You can regenerate all the sizes you have just created and choose which one you wanted to regenerate. You can now get all the code to copy and paste to your function theme file. Now you can use the generated sizes directly into your posts and insert images at the right size ! Now you choose if you want display the size in the post insert image. Now you can regenerate the images one by one in the 'Medias' general pane. Now you can regenerate the images by bulk action in the 'Medias' general pane. Now you can regenerate the image sizes on single attachment edit page.

[image]

Comment: Completely unrelated answer; have you read my question at all?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Have you tried this plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/theia-smart-thumbnails-for-wordpress/3160252

Comment: No. How do you think it would solve my problem? Have you understood my problem at all? Sorry, I'm getting tired of people recommending some generic "set-custom-image-sizes" plugins and code. That's NOT the question.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, 
I have totally understand your question. I am trying to give you closest solution. 
1. Simple image size plugin: Help you for normal crop and hard crop. Desire size required.  Please install and check. 
2. Codecanyon plugin: It will help you to save the image, with the exact look. User can crop the way he want.
We are just giving you the closest solution.

Answer (score -1):

The default image sizes of WordPress are "thumbnail", "medium", "large" and "full" (the size of the image you uploaded). These image sizes can be configured in the WordPress Administration Media panel under Settings > Media. This is how you can use these default sizes with the_post_thumbnail():

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```

see also full documentation in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: You can also give Post Thumbnails your own class using by `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft'), array()); ?>`

and custom size.

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array(200, 200)); ?>`

Comment: I don't understand how this should answer my question, 'So how can I enable this "force resize" feature?'

Comment: you can use this for force any size, the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind, I changed the core. Hurts me on the inside, but for this projects it's the best solution.

Comment: I too am looking for a solution for this exact problem. I don't want to force my clients to have to use photoshop before uploading to reduce an image file side. Any solutions other than hacking the core?

Comment: people, this is not funny ... I, the almighty thread opener get downvoted for posting that actual solution that actually worked. Thanks for your help so far in researching this issue, but now I go back to my own cave...

Comment: Not to mention that changing the core of WordPress doesn't help once you upgrade your core.  Changing the core is never a proper solution... there is always a hook somewhere, you just have to know where to look :)

Comment: yeah, please tell me about that mysterious hook I must have been missing... there is none, that's why the only option to get this to work was changing the core after all... at least back at 2012

Comment: I did tell you about the mysterious hook... in my answer.